# Why isn't the DIV with the image being hidden?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an experiment involving a series of clickable images where a user has to rate an object after clicking on it. The workflow being:

1. User sees the three boxes, one changes color
2. User clicks on the box that changes color
3. User is shown an object (say a skunk)
4. User rates the object by entering in a # into a text input box
5. User sees all three boxes, and the next box changes color

I have the DIV with an id of E1 (representing example 1) set with a default display style of none (set by CSS initially) however it still shows up when I look at the page in my browser. As a result when I should only be seeing a cover.jpg I see E1.jpg along with its associated text input box.

Edit: Oh some of the code isn't completed yet (e.g. JavaScript events for recording the milliseconds taken to rate the object, or hiding or showing other DIVs). I just wanted to resolve the issue of display: none; not hiding anything.

**CSS**

```
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 656px;
    top: 586px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 543px;
    top: 167px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 243px;
    top: 167px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#div.C1 {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}

#div.E1 {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

#div.E2 {
    display: none;
}

#div.E3 {
    display: none;
}

</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    function divHideShow(divToHideOrShow) 
    {
        var div = document.getElementById(divToHideOrShow);

        if (div.style.display == "block") 
        {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else 
        {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }

    }
    function HideDIV(d) 
    { 
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; 
    }
    function ShowDIV(d) 
    { 
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

**Body**

```
<!-- Creates the background for the two screens -->
<div id="ForDualScreen">   
    <img src="Images/Example/House.jpg" width="1280" height="1000" border="0"  style="float:left;" />
    <img src="Images/Black.jpg" width="1280" height="1000" border="0" style="float:right;"/>
</div>  

<a href="javascript:divHideShow('apDiv1');divHideShow('apDiv2');">Show/Hide apDivs on click</a>


  <div id="apDiv1">

            <div id="C1">
            <img src="Images/Example/Cover.jpg" onclick="ShowDIV('E1');HideDIV('C1');" />
            </div>
            <div id="E1">
                <img src="Images/Example/E1.jpg" />
                <br />
                <input name="E1Rating" type="text" size="5" maxlength="1" oninput="Javascript_RTshowCover" />
            </div>
   </div>     

        <div id="apDiv2">
            <img src="Images/Example/Cover.jpg" onclick="Javascript_showDivw/Image&Rating" />
            <div id="E2">
                <img src="Images/Example/E2.jpg"/>
                <br />
              <input name="E2Rating" type="text" size="5" maxlength="1" oninput="Javascript_showCover" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="apDiv3">
            <img src="Images/Example/Cover.jpg" onclick="Javascript_showDivw/Image&Rating" />
            <div id="E3">
                <img src="Images/Example/E3.jpg"/>
                <br />
              <input name="E3Rating" type="text" size="5" maxlength="1" oninput="Javascript_RTMovetoInstruction" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS should simply be

```
#E1 {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Just wow, I can't believe I was that much of an idiot. I was trying to apply class stuff to an ID. No wonder. Haha thanks! I'll accept the answer once the timer is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and the show/hide methods:

- http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- http://api.jquery.com/show/

or even, toggle:

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Here's the related tutorial:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Basic_Show_and_Hide